# Difficulty understanding changes to dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I was looking through old posts in order to find a method of changing values in a dictionary by iterating through the items.

```
dictionary = {
    1: [
        {
            "id": "1234",
            "cow": "parts/sizes/lakes"
        },
        {
            "id": "5151",
            "cow": "minors/parts"
        }
        ]}

def fetchanswers():
    for item in dictionary[1]:
        yield(item["id"], item["cow"])

for a, b in fetchanswers():
    k = {}
    k["id"] = a
    k["cow"] = b.replace("parts", a)
```

My understanding is that yield returns the two items from either object in the dictionary and the for loop creates a new dictionary and appends the values obtained from `fetchanswers()` and `parts` is replaced by `id`.

I don't understand how `k["id"]` can be referred to when the dictionary is empty.

Comment: `k["id"]  =` is **storing** that key, not referring to it.

Comment: You can use the `[]` operator to assign a new value.

Comment: Besides, `id` is a function, so `b.replace("parts", id)` doesn't do what you think it might

Comment: How is it that the dictionary is not empty when it is just created with `k={}`? Do you  mean that it is not empty as soon as `k["id"] =` stores the key?

I noticed that. Typo when changing variables for the post

Comment: Why does it matter if the dictionary is empty or not? `k` is never really used. It's overridden on each loop

Comment: I have limited knowledge and didn't know that the square brackets could assign a new value in a dictionary, so I was confused that it would create something new when the dictionary was empty because up to this point I have only seen them being used to refer to an index.

Comment: Maybe start over from the basics https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> a method of changing values in a dictionary

Your values are strings. Strings are immutable, so you need to overwrite the dictionary using existing keys

You don't need another dictionary for this

```
# replace "parts" text value with the value of the id key 
for item in list_of_dicts:
    item["cow"] = item["cow"].replace("parts", str(item["id"]))
```

> how k["id"] can be referred to

It's not a referral when there's an equal sign afterwards. It's an assignment